# Passing data from a form to a REST endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm kinda new to writing REST endpoints thus this question.
I'm writing a REST endpoint that should support a form submission in iOS that registers an User.

This is my User class.

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long Id;
  private String username;
  private String email;
  private String password;
}
```

This is the controller user signup signature that I've been asked to work with,

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/signup",
                  method = RequestMethod.POST,
                  consumes = {"application/json"})
  public ResponseEntity<?> showRegistrationForm(@RequestBody User user) {
    try{
      //persist the User
      return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

The user object is provided to me using the following JSON payload,

```
{
  "username": "Something",
  "email": "Something",
  "password": "password"
}
```

What I don't understand is how do I grab the fields posted from the form and convert them to the user in a POST request. Wouldn't I need to change the parameters to string, validate them and then compose the User object. Or just what is the right way of doing this. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Browser `<form>` POST doesn't support sending payload as JSON. Are you asking how to write JavaScript code for the Browser to build JSON data and send POST request to the server?

Comment: @Andreas no I will be provided the JSON payload in the format I need. Where does the marshalling of the object into User through jackson take place. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: The Spring Framework does the unmarshaling of JSON to `User` for you. See Spring Framework Reference Documentation: [Mapping the request body with the @RequestBody annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).